# Angular4 and NGINX permission denied

Tags: angular, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I'm unable to run my angular 4 app using nginx. I have checked error.log for nginx i see this

> 2018/04/21 12:49:52 [error] 13961#13961: *1 open()
>   "/root/test/myapp/web-portal/index.html" failed (13:
>   Permission denied)

I'm running all commands using **sudo**. My nginx configuration is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP

        root /root/test/myapp/web-portal/index.html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
        location /admin {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.


                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }

}
```

I have tried chmod but not working for me

```
chmod -R 755 /root/test/myapp/web-portal
```

Comment: may be this is port issue, so try to run on port above 1023

Comment: Show the rights for index file and parent folder. Which user is running nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very good practice to run nginx as root.

You should rather create a user for nginx (if you don't already have one) and then place the website files in a directory whose owner is the nginx user, such as `/var/www`